# Dovecot (imap) not starting

Tags: email, imap, dovecot

I'm running Ubuntu 14.10 installed postfix dovecot vimbadmin and roundcube.

Everything works except dovecot.

When I restart dovecot I get this:

```
stop: Unknown instance: 

dovecot start/running, proccess 6580
```

In my `var/log/dovecot.log` file I get this:

```
Fatal: service(auth) Group doesn't exist: postifx (See service auth { unix_listener /var/run/dovecot/auth-userdb { group } } setting)
```

So i probably have some problems with the settings, i will post those two if its necessary, but i'm hoping maybe someone all ready had this problem and its a quick fix.

Comment: `Group doesn't exist: postifx` - is that a typo?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You presumably have a typo, `postifx` should be `postfix`. Search the dovecot config files for `postifx` and fix those.